# Eclipse Debug Configuration error "program not specified"

Tags: eclipse, arm

I get an error message while configuring the Snapdragon Debugger on an instance of Eclipse. I am using the instructions [here](https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/snapdragon-debugger-eclipse/quick-start-guide) and here is the error I get: [image: Eclipse debug window] Can anyone advise how to select the correct and relevant program?

Comment: What did you do at step 13 of the "Configuration and Launch" guide? I know nothing about this tool, but it strikes me from the screenshot that the suspiciously-blank "C/C++ Application:" field of the dialog should probably be filled in with the path to whatever application you want to debug...

Comment: I right clicked the project and chose "debug configuration". Which does not necessarily pick that project. I am however puzzled since none of the buttons underneath give me anything I recognize as far as the application or program to be debugged.

Comment: I imported this project from another workspace, and tried to build it but the IDE lacks some other patches. So I may have to build it successfully before I can select it for debug. I am basically stuck; one tool works with older version of eclipse and another with the newer version and I need them both.